# Extracting links with scrapy that have a specific css class

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

Conceptually simple question/idea.

Using Scrapy, how to I use use `LinkExtractor` that extracts on only follows links with a given CSS?

Seems trivial and like it should already be built in, but I don't see it? Is it?

It looks like I can use an XPath, but I'd prefer using CSS selectors. It seems like they are not supported?

Do I have to write a custom `LinkExtractor` to use CSS selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want something similar to `restrict_xpaths`, but provide a CSS selector instead of an XPath expression.

This is actually a built-in feature in [*Scrapy 1.0*](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/) (currently in a release candidate state), the argument is called `restrict_css`:

> `restrict_css`
>
> a CSS selector (or list of selectors) which defines regions inside the
>   response where links should be extracted from. Has the same behaviour
>   as restrict_xpaths.

The initial feature request:

- [CSS support in link extractors](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/983)

Comment: That's very good news! Thanks for the info. 

Also, any idea if 1.0 will support Python 3?

I know this might be not be possible yet because of the twisted dependency, but still curious. Would love to have this available in Python 3.

Comment: @lostdorje yeah, from what I know Scrapy devs are working on the Python 3 support but twisted is far from being there, see https://rawgit.com/mythmon/twisted-py3-graph/master/index.html. See also: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/263.